# How can i save a video from an uri, to internal storage?

Tags: xamarin, video, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, save

I'm trying to save a video from an url/uri and also, obtain the video path into the device

I'm working with Xamarin.Forms, using DependencyService to allow access to some functions in the Android Project

```
public string DownloadFile(string url)
        {

            string pathToNewFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, folder);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToNewFolder);

            try
            {
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
                string pathToNewFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathToNewFolder, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(url) + ".mp4");
                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri(url), pathToNewFile);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (OnFileDownloaded != null)
                OnFileDownloaded.Invoke(this, new DownloadEventArgs(null,null,null,null,0));
            }
            return pathToNewFolder;
}
```

I download a file in mp4 format, but I can`t play this video

Answer (score 0):

You can play it by using the package [Xam.Plugins.Android.VlcXamarin](https://github.com/martijn00/VlcXamarin)

### Usage

```
LibVLCLibVLC mLibVLC = null;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

if(mLibVLC == null)
{
    //Initialize VLC libs
    mLibVLC = new LibVLCLibVLC(this);
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(mLibVLC);
}
//Create new media object
var m = new MediaLibVLC(mLibVLC, Android.Net.Uri.Parse( the filepath));

// Tell the media player to play the new Media.
mMediaPlayer.Media = m;

// Finally, play it!
mMediaPlayer.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the file to your internal storage, you just have to modify this base path you are using:

```
string pathToNewFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, folder);
```

Instead of `ExternalStorageDirectory` you can use one of the `System.Environment.SpecialFolder` values which pleases you:

```
System.Environment.SpecialFolder    Path
ApplicationData                     INTERNAL_STORAGE/.config
Desktop                             INTERNAL_STORAGE/Desktop
LocalApplicationData                INTERNAL_STORAGE/.local/share
MyDocuments                         INTERNAL_STORAGE
MyMusic                             INTERNAL_STORAGE/Music
MyPictures                          INTERNAL_STORAGE/Pictures
MyVideos                            INTERNAL_STORAGE/Videos
Personal                            INTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Where `INTERNAL_STORAGE = /data/user/0/com.companyname/files`

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/